# ruby object behavior while using fog and AWS methods

Tags: aws-sdk, fog

I have an aws_helper.rb file

```
require 'yaml'
require 'fog'
class Aws_Helper
  def initialize()
    conf = YAML::load_file("config.yml")
    @connection = Fog::DNS.new( :provider=> 'aws',
                         :aws_access_key_id => conf['aws_access_key'],
                         :aws_secret_access_key => conf['aws_secret_key']
                 )
     return @connetion
  end
end
```

If I use the class from another file, say test.rb

```
require_relative 'aws_helper.rb'
connection  = Aws_Helper.new()
connection.zones.get("ZXASDFS443")
p connection
```

I get the error,

> undefined method `zones' for # (NoMethodError)

But from aws_helper.rb file itself if I do @connection.zone.get("ZXASDFS443") this works fine.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are unable to understand something (as you claim yourself), you cannot be helped by anyone. Not being able to understand something is different from not understanding something (which also don't have to state, as you shouldn't be asking here without self-answering if you do). Please leave out such irrelevant (and hopefully untrue) statements and greetings.

Comment: I thought this was a technical forum.  Did't think i had to be good in English to post questions here. I am not a native English speaker so excuse me for any wrong phrase i have used. I just meant i was not able to make out why that connection object doesn't work in above scenario

Comment: This isn't a technical forum, it is a Q&A site that tries to build a high-quality Q&A database. Educating each other about how to contribute to the quality of the database through edits and comments (especially to new contributors) is one of the differences with a forum. I'm not a native speaker either, and if your English would have been a problem I would have commented about inconsistent use of 'I'/'i' in  mid-sentence.

Comment: I am not sure if this was the answer I was looking for while posting this question here. If you know the answer please answer else please let someone else do. Last thing one would have to worry while asking a question is how to frame their sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from how `initialize` works in Ruby, which is a little weird. In particular, unlike most other methods, `initialize` ignores the return value provided. It will ALWAYS return an instance of the class it is defined upon. So in this case you would get back an Aws_Helper instance (instead of a reference to the connection itself). If you change the name of the method there to something like `connect` it should work the way you have laid out.